# replacing carriage returns with breaks in a string for html asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a multiline textbox in an asp.net user control for typing in content to send a mass email from the site login. The HTML includes a placeholder{Message} which is being filled from the text box with

```
string message = txtbxEmailBody.Text;
message.Replace("\n", "<br />");
message.Replace("\r", "<br />");
message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

string body = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader welcomeEmailReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("htmlpath")))
{
    body = welcomeEmailReader.ReadToEnd();
}
body = body.Replace("{Message}", message);
```

I put replace in for newline carriage return and Environment.NewLine just to be safe but only carriage return should be necessary. when I traced it I found that the replace did nothing, I assume because carriage return is a special charter in the string and is not read literally by the method? Anyway I just need to know how to replace the carriage returns and new lines with breaks for the HTML

Comment: Can you give some sample input?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do NOT update your question with the correct answer, or else no one will understand how the answer solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace` doesn't perform the operation in place. The method instead returns a new instance of the modified string.

Your code doesn't store that returned value anywhere. Try setting the `message` variable like this:

```
string message = txtbxEmailBody.Text
                               .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
                               .Replace("\n", "<br />")
                               .Replace("\r", "<br />");
```

Comment: Oops, I should know better than that, thank you. I changed message.Replace("\r", "<br />"); to  message = message.Replace("\r", "<br />"); and it is functioning properly